# 200%+ width page, how to make an object stay fix centered

Tags: width, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a one page web site with horizontal scrolling and undefined width, and I'd like to know how to keep my logo and navigation centered in all time at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto